# Could someone please explain to me the meaning of もち in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, words, usage

私たちは自然の流れとは別の生活リズムをもち始め、次第に自然との調和を失い始めたのです。
I searched but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: That would be the masu-stem form of 持つ.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but may I ask you one more question?What does "持ち" mean in this sentence?  Is this a "Nを+もって" grammar pattern?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Nを+もって as a grammar pattern". Hopefully naruto's answer clarifies things for you.

Comment: @user3856370 I imagine the OP was asking if this is a variation of the grammatical expression which can be written を以って, meaning "by means of." As pointed out in the answer, it's just a mundane use of 持つ.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to ask. I'll practice asking more specific questions. Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

It's the masu-stem of the verb 持つ ("to have"), followed by [始める](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/03/25/jlptn4-grammar-hajimeru/) meaning "to start to ～". This is one of the most basic usages of 持つ, and there is nothing tricky.

> 私たちは自然の流れとは別の生活リズムを**持ち【もち】始め**
> We **started to have** a different rhythm of life that is different from the flow of the nature, ...

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!!!